# Copy drivers from one Armature to another of the same kind

Tags: armature, drivers

I have a mesh/armature combo, which I developed in a good amount of steps.
The first iteration has drivers for bones which drive other bones of the armature. While developing the neither the armature nor the mesh where topology-wise changed.
In the current last iteration I noticed (too late) that those drivers got
lost somewhere.
The first iteration and the current iteration are in two different files.

How can I copy/transfer those drivers from the first iteration of that armature/mesh to the current last one?

PS: I cannot provide a *.blend file. It is not my decision.

Comment: You can include an screen shot of your problem to improve the clarity of your question.  The screen shot could be a simplified version of your problem.  The original file can remain private. The blend file is not requested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- File append from the menus allows the Blender User to move an armature from one file to the other.

[image]

- Now the two armatures are in the same file.
- Now you can copy and paste Python Scripts or drivers from one armature to the other.  This can be done manually or from another script.  For small amounts of copies I suggest the task be done manually, otherwise via Script.

[image]

- Of course you may be able to just copy and paste the text of the driver from while file to the other.  Two Blender files can be open at once.
- This proposed answer is intended to be a high level guide to complete your task.  This is not a tutorial.
- We have not discussed the particulars of a simple copy of a driver from one object to the other.  The detail required to do so was not given in the original question.

Comment: With the given answer I could copy one driver from one mesh/armature to the other successfully. Unfortunately there a LOTS of drivers to copy. Is there any reliable (regarding the copy process as such) script/addon/plugin known to do a mass-copy of drivers in one go?

Comment: You may change your original question with any new information and requirements.  A coherent discourse is better to solve a problem.